# How to write a function that returns indexes of input vector according to some rules, using repeat, while loop, or other iteration technique

Tags: r, function, while-loop, repeat

I'm trying to write a function that takes a numeric vector as input, and returns the *indexes* of a shorter version of the input vector, according to some rules:

- (a) if all elements are identical, return just the *index* of the first element; i.e., return `1`; else:

  if NOT all elements identical, then test for whether `special_treatment_value` is among them:

  - (b) if `special_treatment_value` is there, return the input vector's *indexes*  except for the indexes of elements where `special_treatment_value` appeared; else:
  - (c) if `special_treatment_value` is not there, return the indexes of the input vector as-is, i.e., `1:length(x)`.

**The problem:** if we ended up in route (b), we might encounter a situation in which all vector elements are now the same. In such case, we would like to iterate through (a) again to minimize to just the first element.

### Example

Let's say that I want to pass the following vectors through my function:

```r
my_vec_1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3)
my_vec_2 <- c(4, 4, 4)
my_vec_3 <- c(1, 2, 1, 4, 1)
my_vec_4 <- c(3, 3, 3, 4)
```

and that:

```r
special_treatment_value <- 4
```

According to my rules, the function should return the outputs:

- for `my_vec_1`: it fits route (c) and thus the output should be `1:5` (indexes of all)
- for `my_vec_2`: it fits route (a) and thus the output should be `1` (index of first)
- for `my_vec_3`: it fits route (b). output should be `1 2 3 5` (indexes of all except for special value's)
- `my_vec_4` demonstrates the problem. My desired output is `1` because first we go through route (b) then *I want* to pass through (a). But right now it doesn't happen and my function (see below) returns `1 2 3` (indexes of all except for special value's).

#### my current attempt

```r
get_indexes <- function(x, special_val) {
  if (var(x) == 0) { # route (a)
    output_idx <- 1
    return(output_idx)
  }
  
  idx_entire_length <- 1:length(x)
  
  if (any(x == special_val)) { # route (b)
    idx_to_remove <- which(x == special_val)
    output_idx    <- idx_entire_length[-idx_to_remove]
    return(output_idx)
  }
  
  # else
  output_idx <- idx_entire_length # route (c)
  return(output_idx)
}

get_indexes(my_vec_1, 4)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
get_indexes(my_vec_2, 4)
#> [1] 1
get_indexes(my_vec_3, 4)
#> [1] 1 2 3 5
get_indexes(my_vec_4, 4)
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

I guess there should be some `repeat` block or `while` loop, but I can't figure out how to implement it correctly (and efficiently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
foo <- function(x, y){
 
  tmp <- which(x != y) 
  
 if(dplyr::n_distinct(x[x!=y])<=1){
   tmp <- 1
 }
  
 return(tmp) 
}
```

Instead `n_distinct()` you can use `length(unique())`

Result:

```
lapply(list(my_vec_1, my_vec_2, my_vec_3, my_vec_4), foo, 4)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 5

[[4]]
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could repeat the condition for going through *(a)* inside condition *(b)*, for example:

```
f <- function(x, treatment){
  if(var(x) == 0) 1 else {
    if(treatment %in% x) {
      x[-which(x == treatment)] |>
        (\(.) if(var(.) == 0) 1 else (1:length(x))[-which(x == treatment)])()
    } else {
      1:length(x)
    }
  }
}

lapply(list(v1, v2, v3, v4), f, 4)

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 5

[[4]]
[1] 1
```